# joomla tag form loads whole list from db

Tags: joomla

I noticed that joomla tag input field is quite stupid. It loads everything from db, in this case 9K tags. Obviously ui becomes so slow.

Any ideas how to fix it? it seems there is already an ajax functionality present, so why not rely on that completely? J ways are crazy.

[image]

1 idea is to modify getOption method, and load only the tags that are related to current article editor is editing.

But in this context I don't seem to have article id.

Any ideas how to solve situation? I'm sure some of you've run into this :S

```
/**
 * Method to get a list of tags
 *
 * @return  array  The field option objects.
 *
 * @since   3.1
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    $published = $this->element['published']? $this->element['published'] : array(0,1);

    $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('DISTINCT a.id AS value, a.path, a.title AS text, a.level, a.published, a.lft')
        ->from('#__tags AS a')
        ->join('LEFT', $db->qn('#__tags') . ' AS b ON a.lft > b.lft AND a.rgt < b.rgt');

    // Filter language
    if (!empty($this->element['language']))
    {
        $query->where('a.language = ' . $db->q($this->element['language']));
    }

    $query->where($db->qn('a.lft') . ' > 0');

    // Filter on the published state
    if (is_numeric($published))
    {
        $query->where('a.published = ' . (int) $published);
    }
    elseif (is_array($published))
    {
        JArrayHelper::toInteger($published);
        $query->where('a.published IN (' . implode(',', $published) . ')');
    }

    $query->order('a.lft ASC');

    // Get the options.
    $db->setQuery($query);

    try
    {
        $options = $db->loadObjectList();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException $e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Block the possibility to set a tag as it own parent
    if ($this->form->getName() == 'com_tags.tag')
    {
        $id   = (int) $this->form->getValue('id', 0);

        foreach ($options as $option)
        {
            if ($option->value == $id)
            {
                $option->disable = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Merge any additional options in the XML definition.
    $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $options);

    // Prepare nested data
    if ($this->isNested())
    {
        $this->prepareOptionsNested($options);
    }
    else
    {
        $options = JHelperTags::convertPathsToNames($options);
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: The point of the tag field is to be able to add tags on the fly.  Unless you weren't allowing editing only allowing the current article tags would be silly.  Further the tag field uses autocomplete so it needs to have a list of tags to check against or you would constantly be creating (and going to the database to save) new tags called "blue" or "BLUE" or whatever that already exist.   The good thing is cache though. Make sure to think about how to set the options.

Comment: @Elin hello, what you say is true, but, Tag field does ajax requests all the time, when I write three letters BLU it sends ajax request and returns json list of tags matching criteria. Why cannot we have fully ajax autocomplete instead of loading all tags from db which causes slow down? Now its not clear why ajax calls are done at all, since everything is preloaded. And what if J has many editors and while 1 editor was writing article created new tag, and your X editors preloaded list doesn't know this. in this case your argument becomes counterargument.

Comment: Actually I didn't do this field at all, you should ask over at joomla.stackexchange.com.  I was looking at that and I don't think it worked that way originally, but if i recall there is some option in the xml that lets you decide how to do it which I agree would be better than acting like it's a dropdown (that was done  for people who freaked out at not having a drop down).  Anyway go ask on [joomla.se] and you can probably find someone to talk to about it.  Or ask on the dev list.

Comment: @Elin interesting part is that docs say there are two modalities, ajax and nested. Unfortunately there is no distinction between two modes, they do the same thing. I've asked there, and I was redirected to you :) http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/joomla-tag-input-preloads-tags-instead-of-ajax-calling-it

Comment: @Elin I fixed it. I disabled list that shows in dropdown, and ajax autocomplete works perfectly without any extra work! it is incredible, so easy...

Comment: Can you post that (with a bit of an explanation) as an answer and accept it?

Comment: @Elin sure, if I did PR on github would J team accept it?

Comment: THat I cannot predict, but it's a simple fix and they might go for it. It'll only take you 10 minutes to make a pr etc so why not do it?   The person who made that field is phproberto and he is on twitter you could talk to him about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've modified list that gets preloaded, only to load tags that are present in the article (saved as belonging to article). Autocomplete still works with ajax so no loss of functionality there.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you change line 140 to `$query->where->($db->quoteName("a.id") . ' IN ' . $value); `

Comment: If `$this->value` elements are not already cast as integers, they should be converted before imploding as a matter of security/stability.  There is no benefit to checking `if (!empty($value))` -- the outcome is already determined by `else`.  There is no stability/security benefit to backtick-wrapping `a.id`. The `IN` keyword will expect a parenthetical expression to follow.